# Compare a floating point number to zero

Tags: c, floating-point

I want to check if an IEEE754 32-bit number has the value of exactly 0.0f (it will occasionally be set to it.) Accumulation errors will be nil as the data will be frequently updated from a sensor. My processor has no hardware FPU, so operations are done in a fairly fast software library. However, it's still hundreds of cycles for things like add, subtract and compare.

So I was wondering why my compiler does this:

```
240:                 if(p_viewer->roll != 0.0f)
 03FBC  B81160     mul.uu w2,#0,w2
 03FBE  900A2E     mov.w [w14+20],w4
 03FC0  900064     mov.w [w4+12],w0
 03FC2  9000F4     mov.w [w4+14],w1
 03FC4  07E91F     rcall __nesf2
 03FC6  E00000     cp0.w w0
 03FC8  320054     bra z, 0x004072
```

__nesf2 apparently compares two floating point numbers. Why doesn't it just do a compare against 0.0f in integer form, which is 0x00000000? Is there some reason it doesn't do this or is it just a missed optimisation opportunity?

My compiler is MPLAB C30, a version of GCC v3.23.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `-0.0f` also compares equal to `0.0f`, as required by the IEEE-754 standard.

You could replace the call with a comparison against the integer representations of both -0 (`0x80000000`) and +0, if this is a major performance issue.  (Or better still, mask the sign bit and compare against `0.0f`).

Comment: I was wondering why the compiler didn't do this, it would probably only be 10 cycles maximum, whereas the __nesf2 function takes about 100 cycles.

Comment: Absent the signaling NaN issue, this is just a missed optimization.  File a bug.

Comment: And considering the age of the compiler (gcc 3.2.3?) it's likely that (a) it has plenty of missed optimizations, and (b) nobody's interested in fixing it.

Comment: @David: If it hasn't already been fixed in gcc mainline, someone will fix it eventually if the bug reports get filed.  Missed optimizations that aren't reported never get fixed.

Comment: @David: It's a fork of GCC v3.23.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a IEEE floating point implementation it has to take into account signalling NAN's.

You may not care about that, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, but does it matter either way? NaN would never compare equal to non-NaN.

Comment: @Thomas O: a signaling NaN could cause a trap, while the integer comparison would not.  However, software FP implementations almost never support signaling NaNs, so this is unlikely.

Comment: @Stephen Canon, I don't think mine has signalling NaNs. You can divide by zero but you only get NaN. Nothing else happens.

Comment: @Thomas O: Division by zero doesn't create a signaling NaN; on implementations that have them, the only way to get a signaling NaN is to read one from a file or create one in memory.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you might try whether your favourite x86 compiler will do anything special for signalling NaNs. It probably won't.

Answer (score 1):

It is a missed optimization opportunity. 0.f is a special case since it has to do a compare with -0.f and 0.f. But still it would be faster to compare as ints.

Why is it not optimized? I would wager that it is an integration problem. Stuff like this usually falls between chairs. The people who have the task to put together the platform SDK pick a compiler (gcc), a software float library, and manage to glue it together in the best way they can. This works OK in the general case, and there is little motivation for improvement, since software floats generally are super slow anyway. The worst part is not comparison, but all the other stuff.

Simply put, if you have software floats, there is no point in using them if you need performance. Use fixed point for that.

Comment: `0.f` is a special case? *Any* floating point values can be compared bit-for-bit as long as you know one of them is not NaN (for instance, if one of them is a literal constant). Actually zero is the worst because you have to check positive and negative zero. For any other value, a single comparison suffices.

Answer (score 0):

To check against 0.0f you don't need IEEE stuff, like:

```
int isFloatNull(float f)
{
  static float i;
  return !memcmp(&i,&f,sizeof i);
}
```

Comment: @kotlinski If it's quicker then it's better, it doesn't matter if it substitutes function calls.

Comment: It will of course give you the wrong result for negative zeroes, so this is quite useless.